# fetch from mysql - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this error.[image]

view

```
            @foreach($lista_sezoane as $lista_sezon)
<option value="">{{ $lista_sezon->select('sezon')->where('id_serial','=','7')->get() }}</option>

            @endforeach
```

db
[image]

Comment: you have to return that from controller , $data = model::select('sezon')->where('id_serial','=','7')->get() ; return view('exemple')->with('data',$data); then in blade just foreach ($data as $season) {{$season}}

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really use blade that way you should instead have some variables in your controller to handle this stuff but blade doesn't stop you from doing that.

Try something like this.

```
@foreach($lista_sezoane as $lista_sezon)
  @foreach($lista_sezon->where('id_serial','7')->get() as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->sezon }}</option>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

For error checking you would want to also ensure your query will return results. This is why a variable would be better but you could also do

```
@if($lista_sezon->where('id_serial','7')->count() > 0)
  ... put foreach statement in here
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function getListaSerial()
    {
        $lista_seriale = Serial::all();
        $lista_sezoane = serialeXsezoane::all();
        return view('admin.seriale.index-seriale',['lista_seriale' => $lista_seriale,'lista_sezoane' => $lista_sezoane]);
    }
```